# Is backdoor type of vulnerability or malware?

Tags: security, malware

I understand what is a backdoor when expressed in terms of type of malware i.e. it provides remote access.
Can one also say that backdoor is a type of vulnerability?
If yes how backdoor as vulnerability related to backdoor as a malware?

Answer (score 0):

Backdoor is an often undocumented feature in a program that provides remote access. It can be intentional and positive (backdoor to company management program that allows managers but not ordinary people access from off-site, for example; or developer-exclusive access so they can tweak the CSS after the deploy), intentional and negative (e.g. developer leaving a back door to delete the application if they are not paid, or to steal corporate information after deploying an unrelated application) or unintentional (where a backdoor functionality is found as a bug).

It is a vulnerability if it is unsecured to any unauthorised access. It is not a vulnerability if it is known and secured to authorised access only.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the use of word 'unsecured' and 'secured' in "It is a vulnerability if it is unsecured to any unauthorised access. It is not a vulnerability if it is known and secured to authorised access only."

Comment: For example, if the scenario is "backdoor to company management program that allows managers but not ordinary people access from off-site", managers have the relevant passwords, while non-managers (including the developer who built the backdoor in) do not, the personnel access is kept up-to-date, and there are no bugs that would prevent the authentication/authorisation to work as intended, then it is a secured back door, and not a vulnerability.

Comment: Imagine a physical house. A literal wooden back door that goes to the garden, with a proper lock, and key that the household adults keep in their pocket - that is a secured back door. If the back door has a glass window, it's a vulnerable back door (has a bug). If the kids take the key and then have it stolen in the school cafeteria, it is a vulnerable back door, as unauthorised people have the key. If the locksmith who built the lock for the back door keeps a copy of the key to himself, without telling (or obtaining permission) from the household, it is an intentionally vulnerable back door.

Comment: In my understanding however secure the backdoor (or hidden account) is, sooner or later it can be detected and there are number of examples for this where hard-coded credentials meant for remote administration have been disclosed.

Comment: There's no problem with detecting a back door _if it's supposed to be there_, and is properly secured (hardcoding credentials does not count as "properly secured"). However, most talk of back doors involves malicious, unintentional or improperly secured back doors, which are vulnerable.

Comment: For example, DRAC (Dell Remote Access Controller) is an intentional back door that allows you alternate access to a computer when the primary access may be unavailable. It is a back door that is very well known (as Dell advertises it), but ideally you will have it on a separate firewall, with tightly controlled list of authorised users, so that system administrators don't need to walk to the server room if the computer is refusing to boot. It is a back door, but it is only a vulnerability if you don't take care of it.

Comment: Ok fine, that means backdoor can be a type of vulnerability. 
Now how backdoor as vulnerability related to or different from backdoor as a malware?

Comment: If a backdoor is intentionally and maliciously built into software in order to provide access to unwitting users, such a software is malware.